# Button press after a delay

Tags: android, button

Hi I am writing my first android app and I want to perform a click after a few seconds. How can I do that?

```
    public void computerMove(boolean butn){
    if(clickOne){
        if(five.isEnabled()){
            five.performClick();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform `onClick` you post a delayed message to a `handler`, specifying as

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 5000);
```

and call runnable as

```
private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       //call performClick  here
    }
 };
```

In this onclick function will be called after 5 seconds/5000 milliseconds.

See more info at [Handler PostDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

Comment: thank you! I will vote up as soon as I do this part!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can uese `PostDelay Handler`

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
mHandler = new Handler();
mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //YOUR_BUTTON_LISTENER
          button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }// end of onClick

    });//end of button listener
    return true;
}// end of Run
    };// end of runnable    
    ...
    ...
    //note that, the delay time is in milliseconds
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, DELAY_TIME_OUT);
```